# Iterating through dataframe in Pyspark to perform further calculations

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with python/pySpark in Jupyter Notebook and I am trying to figure out the following:

I've got a dataframe like this:

```
id    name    degrees_id
1      A         51
2      B         12
3      C         13
```

And another one like

```
degrees_id    val
    51         2
    12         3
    12         4
    51         2
    51         2
```

The dataframe I'm trying to get looks like this:

```
name    sum_val
 A         6
 B         7
```

Thus far I've just collected the dataframes:

```
df1 = hc.sql("select * from dataframe1")
df2 = hc.sql("select * from dataframe2")
```

How do I iterate over all rows of df1 so that I can query inside the df2 to sum for every val corresponding to each name (through degrees_id)? I'm very new to spark so perhaps I'm still unable to wrap my head around the conceptual creation of this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum

df1.join(df2, ["degrees_id"], "inner").groupBy("name")\
    .agg(sum("val").alias("sum_val")).show()

+----+-------+
|name|sum_val|
+----+-------+
|   A|      6|
|   B|      7|
+----+-------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! How would I go about this if after groupBy I wanted to iterate over the rows and do some more calculations? Like a '%like%' statement or data type conversion and eventually sum?

Comment: You can read about [filter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=filter#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter) and [withColumn](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=withcolumn#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn) functions ini these links.
Something like `df.filter(df.column.like('%s%')).show()` and  `.withColumn(‘column', col("column").cast("string”))` for like and cast operations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do a merge and groupby:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on='degrees_id')
   .groupby('name', as_index=False)['val'].sum()
)
```

Output:

```
  name  val
0    A    6
1    B    7
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I can merge in pyspark. I'm trying a join right now. :/